# In what ways can I take advantage of the elements an enemy spellcaster is charging?

Tags: magicka

One of the loading screen tips in Magicka urges you to notice the elements enemy spellcasters are preparing so that you may use that to your advantage. So far the only ways I've found to take advantage of such information is to set up a shield to reflect beams, or cast a corresponding elemental resistance on myself.

Are there additional, and perhaps more offensive, ways of taking advantage of the elements an enemy spellcaster is planning to use?

Comment: I remember if you cross beams with elements that can't work together, you blow up yourself and the enemy? Is that offensive enough for you? ;). But if the enemy is mostly casting for example electric attacks you can make him wet so it hurts himself when he casts.

Comment: Well, I was going to post exactly this as an answer... why didn't you?

Comment: @RafaelCelerier Yes, why didn't you? I can't accept a comment as the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you cross beams of elements that negate each other, you blow up yourself and the enemy.

Also, if the enemy is casting electrical attacks, mostly, you can make him wet so that charging electricity causes him damage.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple things you can do offensively. The first, as already noted, is to make the enemy Wet if you see him conjure lightning elements frequently. The easiest ways to do this are either the Rain magick [QQF] or Large Splash Bombs [QQQQD]. This will force the enemy to ether stop using lightning, or more likely alter his resistance or activate a personal shield to counter getting wet - which you can exploit offensively.

The second, more devious plan is to cast the Nullify magick [SE] when he is in the middle of a complex conjuration sequence. This will remove all shields, walls, buffs, and more importantly, already conjured elements - leaving your opponent with a dud spell. While he is trying to figure out how to add the missing elements again or get rid of it and shield himself again, you can move in to attack with basically anything. He will have no armor, wards, or magic resistance aura, and it will be difficult for him to create one quickly with a few random elements in hand.

Comment: Very insightful! Might I add that my favorite way of getting enemies wet is using any sort of beam/steam combination.

Comment: Steam beams are great at long range, but unfortunately don't work against targets who are behind cover.